# total number for matched words, in python for loop

Tags: python

I have a question about Python's for-loop. This code gives the `gratio` of matched words. `gratio` is float, with final output that looks like this:

```
2.45
1.74
3.38
4.15
```

How can I make the code below match the total of the numbers above? The total should be `11.72`, but it is not producing that.

```
f = open('testword.txt')
for word in f.read().splitlines():
    for i in data:
        a = (i["keyword"])
        if word == a:
            b = i["gratio"]
            c = float(b)
            d = (c * 100)
            e = (round(d, 2))
```

Comment: You need to store these numbers in a list and then add them using the `sum()` function, or keep a running total and add to it every time you print the gratio of a word. When you say "I tried but couldn't solve it", you need to _show your attempt at solving the thing you're asking about_. "Implement this for me" is [off-topic](/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: `f += e` inside your loop, and then print that at the end?

Comment: Be sure to provide a minimal, compilable example of your code. Here, we do not know what is in your `testword.txt` file, nor is the variable `data` instantiated. While you provide some outputs the code as-is is not clear about how it's outputting values at all.

Comment: I solved the issue by storing the numbers in a list and using sum() function. Also, I will be more careful at giving further details. Thanks!